# On closure of a set in ordered square

Tags: general-topology

I am reading Munkres topology by myself. While doing exercises in chapter "Closed sets & Limit points", In exercise 18(b) it is asked to find closure of a set $B=\{(1-\frac{1}{n}) \times \frac{1}{2} : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$
I can see easily that $(1,0)$  is limit point of the set B. But while proving no other point in ordered square is limit point of B, I get confused why elements of type $(1-\frac{1}{n},0)$ cant be limit points of B. If Basic open set of type $((a,b),(c,d))$ contains $(1-\frac{1}{n},0)$ then it must contain $(1-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{2})$ and it is an element of B other than $(1-\frac{1}{n},0)$. Thus every neighbourhood of $(1-\frac{1}{n},0)$ contains a point of B other than $(1-\frac{1}{n},0)$. 
Is this wrong approach? Please tell me where i am doing wrong or give me hint to discard these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dictionary order can be very confusing, at first!

For example, let's consider the point $\frac23\times 0.$ You seem to be claiming (for example) that every neighborhood of this point is also a neighborhood of $\frac23\times\frac12.$ However, the interval $\left(\frac12\times\frac12,\frac23\times\frac12\right)$ is a neighborhood of $\frac23\times 0$ that contains no elements of $B.$

No element of $B$ is a limit point of $B,$ either, since for any $x\in[0,1],$ the interval $\left(x\times0,x\times 1\right)$ has at most one point of $B$ in it.

Does that give you an idea how one might show that no point $x\times y$ with $x<1$ is a limit point of $B$?

Comment: Thank you cameron sir! With your example now i am cleared which type of basic open sets doesn't contain (1-1/n,0). And you said it right, with dictionary order i am getting unexpected cloures and limit points!

Comment: You are very welcome!